# How to create an audio journal in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: audio, language-agnostic, ubuntu, audio-recording, audio-player

I understand that this question might be a little broad, but I am wanting to make an audio recording and playback program to act as a journal. What is the best way to go about this?

I have never done any programming with sound before and really have no idea where to even start, but I do understand that I am probably going to need codecs and interface my program with specific libraries available in Ubuntu. So, to make things a little more specific:

- What libraries should I look at for recording and playback?
- Are there any reliable resources that show how to effectively use these libraries?

The first question takes precedence of course, as I can use Google to find the answers to the second question myself.

A couple of Google searches didn't really provide specifics for what I am wanting to do here, so I thought I would ask the experts. However, if the question is unsuitable, let me know and I will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for you to use I would pick a scripting language with reasonable library coverage (perl, python, ruby) and then glue together the various modules needed.

In terms of architecture you could just have a folder of audio recordings, write a command-line tool that when run starts recording what you say until you press Control-D - then plays it back, asks "OK? 'Y/N'", and if you say Y saves it to the folder.  You could then write a little web page generator that creates an index.html to the recordings.